# T-SQL results have J prefix

Tags: sql-server-express

SQL Server Express. My table 'weather' contains two relevant columns:

```
snapdate (date)
temp (decimal 18,2)
```

`snapdate` contains a date like `2023-07-30`

My query is intended to return the maximum and minimum temperatures for every date,

```
SELECT snapdate "Date", MAX(temp) "Max", MIN(temp) "Min"
FROM weather
WHERE SUBSTRING(CAST(snapdate AS char), 1, 4) = '2021'
GROUP BY snapdate
ORDER BY snapdate ASC
```

The unexpected results look like this:

```
Date            JMax                 JMin
----------------J--------------------J--------------------
      2013-04-04J                3.00J                 .40
      2013-04-05J                6.80J                 .90
etc
```

The max and min temps are correct for each date.

The 'J' is a prefix, and I don't understand why it's there or what it's telling me. Can anybody enlighten me?

Ran the query both from the command line and contained in a stored procedure with the same results.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Your `CAST(snapdate AS char)` most likely results in the first character of the current month - `J` for `July` - to be output. If you want the whole date - you should specify a length! And use `varchar` instead of char, too !  Try `CAST(snapdate AS VARCHAR(50))` or something like that ...

Comment: Is this in `sqlcmd` or in SSMS? If the former, have you used the `-s` parameter, or do you have the `SQLCMDCOLSEP` environement variable set? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#-s-col_separator

Comment: Eventually I got rid of the problem: I think it was using varchar without a length. Thanks!